# Magento 2 - Error using around Plugin

Tags: magento2, php, plugin

I need to change the value of the shipping cost when the user select the shipping address on my magento 2 checkout. Using some params of the products they are buying and the params of the shipping address.

So I decide to create a Plugin to execute some code before and after shipping is selected. Reading on magento 2 documentation ([Plugins (Interceptors) | Magento 2 Developer Documentation](http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/extension-dev-guide/plugins.html)) I created an `aroundMethod()`. Well I created and I added only the sample code I got from the documentation and a simple `var_dump()` but when I execute the code on my checkout I get this javascript error:

`Cannot read property 'items' of undefined at ko.subscription.callback (totals.js:18)`

This seems like my plugin doesn't return something of necessary.

This is my Plugin:

The declaration on `<vendor>\<module>\etc\di.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/con
fig.xsd">
     <type name="Magento\Checkout\Model\ShippingInformationManagement">
         <plugin name="get_shipping_info" type="<vendor>\<module>\Plugin\ShippingCalculate" sortOrder="1" disabled="false"/>
     </type>
</config>
```

Then my plugin code `<vendor>\<module>\Plugin\ShippingCalculate`

```
<?php

namespace <vendor>\<module>\Plugin;

class ShippingCalculate
{

    /**
     * @var \Magento\Checkout\Model\Session
     */
    protected $_checkoutSession;

    /**
     * @var \Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http
     */
    protected $_request;

    /**
     * @var \Magento\Quote\Api\CartRepositoryInterface
     */
    protected $_quoteRepository;

    /**
     * @var \Magento\Catalog\Model\ProductFactory
     */
    protected $_productFactory;

    /**
     * ShippingCalculate constructor.
     * @param \Magento\Checkout\Model\Session $checkoutSession
     * @param \Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http $request
     * @param \Magento\Quote\Api\CartRepositoryInterface $quoteRepository
     * @param \Magento\Catalog\Model\ProductFactory $productFactory
     */
    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Checkout\Model\Session $checkoutSession,
        \Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http $request,
        \Magento\Quote\Api\CartRepositoryInterface $quoteRepository,
        \Magento\Catalog\Model\ProductFactory $productFactory
    )
    {
        $this->_checkoutSession = $checkoutSession;
        $this->_request = $request;
        $this->_quoteRepository = $quoteRepository;
        $this->_productFactory = $productFactory;
    }

    /**
     * @param \Magento\Checkout\Model\ShippingInformationManagement $shipping
     * @param callable $proceed
     */
    public function aroundSaveAddressInformation(
        \Magento\Checkout\Model\ShippingInformationManagement $shipping,
        callable $proceed,
        $cartId,
        \Magento\Checkout\Api\Data\ShippingInformationInterface $addressInformation
    )
    {
        $quote = $this->_quoteRepository->getActive($cartId);
        var_dump($quote->debug());
        echo $cartId;

        $returnValue = $proceed($cartId, $addressInformation);
        if ($returnValue) {
            // No Code here
        }
        return $returnValue;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You are doing `var_dump` and `echo` in the code. This ends up being send in the response and it is not parsed properly on the frontend because the response is not a valid json. Remove them and all should work.